# question about time change for filtration

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I have a question:

Let $T$ be a bounded stopping time and let $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a filtration satisfying the usual conditions. Define $\mathcal{G}_t:=\mathcal{F}_{T+t}$, $t\geq 0$. Then $(\mathcal{G}_t)_{t\geq 0}$ satisfies also the usual conditions.

If $\widetilde{X}=(\widetilde{X}_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a right-continuous submartingale with respect to $(\mathcal{G}_t)_{t\geq 0}$ with $\widetilde{X}_0=0$ then show that $Y:=(Y_t:=\widetilde{X}_{\max(t-T,0)})_{t\geq 0}$ is a submartingale with respect to $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq 0}$.

Does someone have an idea, many thanks!

Comment: I did not understand what is the difference between $\mathcal{G}_t$ and $\mathcal{F}_t$ the way you defined them?

Comment: sorry for the wrong definition of $\mathcal{G}_t$....